# Changing img src in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want an image to change once a user has scrolled down the page (the image is the same size, but different color):

**HTML**

```
<ul class="social-media-nav-center">
  <li>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img id="twitter" class="small" src="path/to/image-icon.png" /> 
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){      
    if($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height()) {
      $("#twitter").attr("src", "../path/to/image-color-icon.png");
    }
  })
})
```

When I scroll down the page, the image is not recognizable, it just comes up as a question mark.

**NOTE**

The image paths are valid, trust me.

-

I feel it's a really simple fix, any ideas?

Comment: Probably because the path is invalid? Check the network tab for the error.

Comment: why the `../` in the JS src when the HTML does not have it? Do you realize the src is based off html file location, not the JS file location?

Comment: The image path is valid, I'm able to check to see if the path is valid in my text editor. @jumbopap

Comment: in the HTML, it's the index.html which is in the root folder, so I do not need to go back a directory. The JS file is in a directory in the root folder, so I needed to go back a directory. @epascarello

Comment: In the ``console`` tab verify that there is no error, my be the access to the image is forbidden in this case try to ``chmod`` your directory if you are using linux or mac

Comment: Is your 'image-icon.png' is working properly for the first time ?

Comment: When are you expecting this condition ($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height()) to true?

Comment: I see that there is in fact an error coming up, but I'm not sure what information you want me to provide. Any specifics? @hamism

Comment: Provide the error string that comes up in the console?

Comment: Yes, the original image is working perfectly. @MayurPatel

Comment: I am expecting that condition when the document is ready, when I scroll down around 700px, it attempts to change it. @SanjayKumarNS

Comment: you have to change $(window).height() to some element height or static value. $(window).height() returns the height of the entire window which we cannot scroll beyond that height.

Comment: The path that it was saying was correct was really incorrect. It was my error. I have given it the correct path. I'm never using Adobe Brackets again. I'm sorry for the inconvenience everyone.

Comment: This is the best part of this question: "The image paths are valid, trust me." !!!

Comment: I thought you said the paths were right...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check to

HTML

```
<ul class="social-media-nav-center">
  <li>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img id="twitter" class="small" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRgdlWvqZIB0r6qkjFS_t9uMKD9gQIVMV3fE-Vw9BMoRfNEmJG2" /> 
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Jquqey

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){      
    if($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height()) {
      $("#twitter").attr("src", "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/744081-background-wallpaper.jpg");
    }
  })
})
```

CSS

```
.social-media-nav-center{height:1000px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yakcbanL/

Comment: I will mark as correct because my text editor deceived me. The path that it was saying was correct was really incorrect. It was my error. I have given it the correct path.

Comment: how could someone downvote this answer when OP has accepted it. Downvoters please comment before downvoting. This will help people to correct or improve the solution provided.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
var path='path/to/image-color-icon.png'
$("#twitter").attr("src", path);
```

Comment: This do the same as it's happening in question. What's new in this ?