# Displaying different logos

Tags: javascript, html, css

URL: http://94.23.211.70/~cairngorm/

The task I am trying to carry out is to change the logo when the navigation switches to the fixed header navigation on scroll. I've tried to use Javascript that I've researched via Google and here but nothing seems to click, maybe I was borderline close to solving it but I'm not sure.

When you visit the link you'll see two logos on each navigation, I was wondering if it was possible to have display:none as an idea which could solve this in a really simple format. If I can't do it through CSS I was wondering if there was a way to do display:none through inline styling within the page since it's easy to do due to being static?

I've tried various methods here but just no light at the end of the tunnel so unless JavaScript or another method is strongly recommended, I'd appreciate any input for this.

Dev

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Show effort and code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283205/jquery-window-scrolling-event

Comment: Okay guys this question is 1. not bad, read it. 
It clearly explains what he wants, and how to do it , 1. css or 2. javascript

Comment: Sorry I'd easily describe the code but I was just wondering if it was possible to use inline styling and have display:none but specify that image - One for the main navigation and switch it for fixed navigation just to save getting javascript involved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758434/changing-img-src-in-jquery/34758522#34758522

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather in your question, you want the logo in your navigation to change based on where the user has scrolled to.

If they're on the hero banner, then show the white edged logo, if they've scrolled then show the black edged logo.

This takes a little bit of JavaScript and jQuery and should get you your desired output

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function checkScroll() {
    // check if the header has changed to be sticky
    if($('header').hasClass('sticky-open')) {
      // hide all logos 
      $('.fly-wrap-logo a').hide(); 
      // only show the last logo (the one with the black edge)
      $('.fly-wrap-logo a:last-child').show(); 
    } else { 
      // hide all logos
      $('.fly-wrap-logo a').hide(); 
      // only show the first logo (the one with the white edge)
      $('.fly-wrap-logo a:first-child').show(); 
    }
  }
  // Run on ready
  checkScroll();

  // Run when the page is scrolled
  $(document).scroll(function() { 
    checkScroll(); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Considering the function has to run on both page load and on a page scroll i thought it best to let it have its own function.

Comment: Also a good answer, thanks for this. I've tried both and both work just fine but this one tops it a little more since I don't have the white logo at the beginning of the new navigation that floats.

Comment: Have a look at temp URL Stewartside if it helps but when you scroll back it sticks with the black logo. Is there a way to revert it to white for the main navigation?

Comment: @Dev it doesn't for me? still doing it now? May have been a caching issue

Comment: Yeah I've been clearing cache and it does work BUT it's a hit and miss. I'm saying hit and miss because I've went through the pages and scrolled down and up for testing and it's going back to white or remaining black.

Answer (score 1):

try this function & CSS

Function

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   if($('header').hasClass('sticky-open')) {
          $('.fly-wrap-logo a:first-child').hide();
          $('.fly-wrap-logo a:last-child').show();
        }

        else {
            $('.fly-wrap-logo a:first-child').show();
          $('.fly-wrap-logo a:last-child').hide();
        }
});
```

CSS

```
.fly-wrap-logo a:last-child{display:none;}
```

**try to only css no jquery**

```
.fly-wrap-logo a{display:none;}
header .fly-wrap-logo a:first-child{display:inline;}
header.sticky-open .fly-wrap-logo a:first-child{display:none;}
header.sticky-open .fly-wrap-logo a:last-child{display:inline;}
```

Comment: Yep, works great. Thanks for taking the time to help out. Means alot, Lalji !

Comment: I've uploaded it onto FTP so you can check out that URL to see it for yourself. When the fixed navigation comes into play, the white logo exists for a short period of time then goes into the black logo. I'm not very savvy with Javascript but I assume that the 365 and 366 has something to do with sorting this? Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: It's because the above function works on a scroll position based instead of on class based. you could just change the number for when it changes the logo